# Как реализовать ожидание ответа пользователя Telegram Bot

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Как реализовать ожидание ответа пользователя Telegram Bot.

1. Жму на кнопку "Авторизоваться"
2. Бот выводит "Введите ваше ФИО",
3. Я записываю в файл ID диалога, и стадию вопроса.
4. Если стадия "fio", то текст следующего сообщения это ФИО.

У меня ошибка в 4 пункте. Я вижу её, и понимаю, почему. Но я не понимаю, как сделать правильно.

```
if ($text == '/start') {
        TG::sendMessage($chatId, 'Здравствуйте!', [['Авторизоваться']]);
    }
    if ($text == 'Авторизоваться') {
        TG::sendMessage($chatId, 'Введите ваше ФИО');
        write($userId, 'stage', 'fio');
        $stage = read($userId, 'stage');
    };
    
    if ($stage == 'fio') {
        write($userId, 'fio', $text);
    }
```

Comment: "У меня ошибка в 4 пункте. Я вижу её, и понимаю, почему." Ты думаешь, мы тут через пространство-время тоже видим эту ошибку? Так вот __нет, не видим__.

Comment: Предполагаю тут проблема в самом алгоритме. По видимому коду можно заметить что `$stage` не будет существовать при повторном запросе (запросе с ФИО) и, следовательно, алгоритм не попадёт в нужное русло.

Answer (score 0):

Понятия не имею, что за функции `write` и `read`, но если предположить, что они работают нормально, то вот эту строку надо вынести из if'а:

```
$stage = read($userId, 'stage');
```